# org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465

Tags: java, email, tomcat, jakarta-mail

I have a Maven project, use JSF 2.2, Tomcat 7 and use `Apache Commons` for sending e-mail.

Here is my code

```
try {
    // Create the email message
    HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
    email.setSmtpPort(465); //email.setSslSmtpPort("465");
    email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
    email.addTo("test@gmail.com", "test");
    email.setFrom(getEmail(), getName());
    email.setSubject(getSubject());
    email.setHtmlMsg("<html>Test</html>"); // set the html message
    email.setTextMsg(getText());// set the alternative message
    email.send();// send the email
} catch (EmailException e) {
    logger.error("Exception sending email: ", e);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    logger.error("Exception sending email: ", ex);
}
```

When I tried to run the code in Tomcat 7, I got the following exception:

> org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the
>   following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:465

Comment: The standard `javax.mail` API has nothing like `HtmlEmail`. It belongs to Apache Commons.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be because the SMTP relay requires authentication, you must login with a gmail user / pass before you can use the relay.

I have never used commons email before, but after some googling, [i found this](https://gist.github.com/ipingu/7681247#file-apache-commons-email-java) for sending an email through gmail.

```
HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();

String authuser = "user";
String authpwd = "pass";

email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(authuser, authpwd));

email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");

// properties to configure encryption
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.debug", "true");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.port", "587");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.port", "587");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.class",   "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
email.getMailSession().getProperties().put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed the code but now i get the excpetion _org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.gmail.com:25_

Comment: i have the same